# Custom Cursor, modify size when click with React

Tags: css, reactjs, css-selectors, mouse-cursor, custom-cursor

I've made a custom cursor on my react app, but I would like to animate it when the user click. Like to decrease the size or something like that. The cursor is in a components that I've call on my Index.js file. I don't know how to make a addlisterner element who change the class of the cursor. I'm new in web development if someone wants to help me, it will be grate :)

Here's the Custom Cursor component :

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react'

function CustomCursor() {

const cursorRef = useRef(null)

React.useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', (event)=>  {
        const {clientX, clientY} = event;
        const mouseX = clientX - cursorRef.current.clientWidth /2;
        const mouseY = clientY - cursorRef.current.clientHeight /2;
        cursorRef.current.style.transform = `translate3d(${mouseX}px, ${mouseY}px, 0)`
    })
}, [])

    return ( <div className='custom-cursor' ref={cursorRef}></div> ) }

export default CustomCursor
```

The css class in detail :

```
.custom-cursor {
  z-index: 9999;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #8c8c8cb8;
  pointer-events: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: fixed;
}
```

I really don't know what to try :/

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by adding the click event listener to the `document` or `window` object and updating the cursor style by adding the CSS class or using the HTML element's JS `style` property. And after some time, removing though changes.

Custom Cursor style when clicked -

```css
.custom-cursor.clicked {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}
```

Event listener for click event -

```
const handleCursorClick = () => {
    // change the cursor styles
    cursorRef.current.classList.add("clicked");

    // OR make changes using the direct using JS for example
    // cursor.current.style.width = '15px'
    // cursor.current.style.height = '15px'

    setTimeout(() => {
      // after some time removes though changes
      cursorRef.current.classList.remove("clicked");

      // cursor.style.width = '20px'  <-- base style
      // cursor.style.height = '20px' <-- base style
    }, 100);
  };
```

Comment: Hi have tried but taht's not working, maybe I've made a mistake on my code ? Could you check it please ? Here's the code sandbox link : https://codesandbox.io/s/custom-cursor-kgheqf?file=/src/CustomCursor.jsx

Comment: For some reason, `onClick` on the `div` is not working, so the another way of adding an event listener is using the `addEventListener` method. Here is the link to the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/customcursor-q93nqm).

Answer (score 0):

You can animate the UI either by adding event listener to the `window` object or the
custome cursor itself,

Here is the working code :

```
function CustomCursor() {
  const [isClicked, setClicked] = useState(false);
  const cursorRef = useRef(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
 // set a slight delay to take effect on mouse move
    let timer;
// Get ClientX of Mouse pointer on the Window
    const mouseX = (event) => event.clientX;

// Get ClientY of Mouse pointer on the Window
    const mouseY = (event) => event.clientY;

// Calculate Pos'n of Cursor/mouse
    const positionElement = (event) => {
      const mouse = {
        x: mouseX(event),
        y: mouseY(event)
      };
      cursorRef.current.style.top = mouse.y + "px";
      cursorRef.current.style.left = mouse.x + "px";
    };
    const onMove = (event) => {
      timer = setTimeout(positionElement(event), 1);
    };

// add `mousemove` listner for window
    window.addEventListener("mousemove", onMove);

    return () => {
    //Clear Intervalid on Unmount
      clearInterval(timer);
    };
  }, []);

// Mouse click handler
  const onClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setClicked((pre) => !pre);
  };

// Change class here
  const clickedClass = isClicked ? "-clicked" : "";

  return (
    <div
      onClick={onClick}
      className={`custom-cursor${clickedClass}`}
      ref={cursorRef}
    ></div>
  );
}

export default CustomCursor;
```

Check this working [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-nova-l45ife?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: HI thank you a lot for your reponse, but I think I did not express myself well, I want to animate the cursor on click, like when you click the cursor take a width of 10px, and 1 second after the click the width come back to 20px. Here's the code sandbox if you know how I can do this : https://codesandbox.io/s/custom-cursor-kgheqf?file=/src/CustomCursor.jsx :)

Comment: Just change ```pointer-events: none ```  to  ```pointer-events: all```  in your class ```custom-cursor```  will get you the expected results,